# Express.js route for html imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm a PHP developer attempting node.js using express.js libraries for the first time.  I've gotten a simple node.js static server running using `express.static`and am now trying to move on to routing.

I have this routing rule:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: path.join(__dirname, '/finished')});
});
```

which returns index.html (url:localhost:port) fine, my problems are when I attempt to import from other directories in index.html's folder.  I always get a 404 error.

Do I have to write rules for every file requested?  Is there anyway to make a folder, or group of folders public?

Example (this works):

```
app.get('/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js', function (req, res){
    res.sendFile('./components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js');
});
```

There must be a way better way to do this.  Any assistance and documentation appreciated, can't seem to connect the dots.

**EDIT**
express.static usage:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/root'));
```

Comment: Well, what does your `express.static()` usage look like?

Comment: Does `__dirname + '/root/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js` exist? Or is it that you have *multiple*, *separate* public asset directories?

Comment: it does exist.  My express.static code GETs the file from the above path fine.  I am actually using Polymer so index.html is referencing items from a single folder called components, so /root/components.

Comment: Also adding the above rule successfully gets the file.

Comment: You can just use the static middleware multiple times with different paths, e.g. `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/root')); app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/components'));` to make both the root folder and the components folder available.